# Problems with improper integrals in higher dimensions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Calculating numerically certain energy integrals in three and four dimensions related to
[the Riesz potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_potential#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Riesz%20potential,Riemann%E2%80%93Liouville%20integrals%20of%20one%20variable)
and [the capacity](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Capacity), I try

```
NIntegrate[ 1/Sqrt[(x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 + (z - r)^2], {x, y, z} \[Element] 
Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1], {p, q, r} \[Element] Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1], 
AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3, WorkingPrecision -> 25, 
Exclusions -> {(x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 + (z - r)^2 == 0}]
```

> `0`

and a warning message
"NIntegrate::moptxn: The option SymbolicProcessing of the method FiniteElement is not one of {Method,MeshOptions}."
As far as I understand it, this means that the `NIntegrate` command does not accept the set of the integration
in the form `{x, y, z} \[Element] Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1], {p, q, r} \[Element] Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1]`. However, if it is so,
the input, not `0`, should be returned.

My next try is

```
 NIntegrate[ 1/((x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 + (z - r)^2)^(1/2), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2], Sqrt[1 - x^2]}, 
{z, -Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {p, -1, 1}, {q, -Sqrt[1 - p^2], Sqrt[1 - p^2]}, 
{r, -Sqrt[1 - p^2 - q^2], Sqrt[1 - p^2 - q^2]}, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3, WorkingPrecision -> 25, 
Exclusions -> {(x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 + (z - r)^2 == 0}]
```

> `-1244.482640558337558417913`

and a warning
"NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 54 recursive bisections
in z near {x,y,z,p,q,r} = <<1>>. NIntegrate obtained -1244.482640558337558417913
and 3534.518334552443660338233`25. for the integral and error estimates."
A similar issue with

```
NIntegrate[1/((x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 + (z - r)^2)^(1/2)*
Boole[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && p^2 + q^2 + r^2 <= 1], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, {p, -1, 1}, 
{q, -1, 1}, {r, -1, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3, WorkingPrecision -> 25, 
Exclusions -> {(x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 + (z - r)^2 == 0}]
```

> `-1203.034524853306755966531`

I wonder  negative numbers since the integrand is positive.
Then i switch to MonteCarlo methods.

```
NIntegrate[ 1/((x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 + (z - r)^2)^(1/2)*
Boole[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && p^2 + q^2 + r^2 <= 1], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, {p, -1, 1}, 
{q, -1, 1}, {r, -1, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 2, WorkingPrecision -> 25, 
Exclusions -> {(x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 + (z - r)^2 == 0},Method -> "QuasiMonteCarlo"]
```

> `21.12327556039856680489716`

and a warning "NIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge after 50000 integrand evaluations.
NIntegrate obtained 21.12327556039856680489716`25.  and 0.2251832352724191939747851`25. for the integral and error estimates.".
A more or less reliable result is obtained by

```
NIntegrate[ 1/((x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 + (z - r)^2)^(1/2)*
Boole[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && p^2 + q^2 + r^2 <= 1], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, {p, -1, 1}, 
{q, -1, 1}, {r, -1, 1},  AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 2, WorkingPrecision -> 25, 
Exclusions -> {(x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 + (z - r)^2 == 0}, Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]
```

> `20.32729987338035891791629`

without any warning. Unfortunately,  `AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3` is not achieved.
Also this works in eight dimensions:

```
NIntegrate[1/((x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 + (z - r)^2 + (w - s)^2)^((4 - 2)/2)*
Boole[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 <= 1 &&  p^2 + q^2 + r^2 + s^2 <= 1], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z,-1, 1}, 
{w, -1, 1}, {p, -1, 1}, {q, -1, 1}, {r, -1, 1}, {s, -1, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 2, 
WorkingPrecision -> 25,Exclusions -> {(x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 + (z - r)^2 + (w - s)^2 == 0}, 
Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]
```

> `25.78510573458365881830859`

BTW, the `Exclusions` option works in the above: compare with `24.68762920929857902438239` without it.

The questions arise: what are other methods to calculate such integrals?
is a three-digit result possible with MonteCarlo methods?

Answer (score 4):

Your first integral might  be solved in two steps!

As far as I know, Finite Element Meshing is only provided up to dimension 3 in Mathematica.  The error message "...method FiniteElement "  led me to a stepwise approach, which works without  error message:

```
int[p_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[(x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 + (z - r)^2], {x, y, z} \[Element]Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1] ]    

NIntegrate[int[p , q , r ], {p, q, r} \[Element] Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1]]
(*21.0552*)
```

Comment: My first feedback: your code is running  without any result on my comp during more than15 minutes.

Comment: +1. Thank you: it works. Few remarks.(i) The execution takes approximately 30 minutes on my comp. (ii) It does not work for the four-dimensional
unit ball. (iii) Don't understand too much difference between `21.0552` produced by your code and
 `20.32729987338035891791629` produced by `AdaptiveMonteCarl` with  `AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 2, WorkingPrecision -> 25`. 
If I correctly understand it, this option guarrantees the relative error 0.01.